# Authorization header is stripped down in put request from browser but working fine in Postman

Tags: django, reactjs, authorization, httprequest

Mine Authorization token in getting stripped down from request from browser(reactjs using axios) to Django server and hence getting 401(unauthorized) but the same request is working fine with the postman. code for the request

```
const config = {
        headers:{
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.token}`
        }
     }
    console.log(config.headers.Authorization)
    console.log(localStorage.token)

    axios.put('http://localhost:8000/user-registration/', config).then(
         res => {
            console.log(res.status)
         } 
      )
}
```

Djnago method

```
class UserRegistrationEvent(APIView):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,) 
authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, ) 
def get_object(self, username):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(username = username)
    except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def put(self, request, format=None):
    print(request.headers)
    User       = self.get_object(request.user)
    serializer = UserRegistrationEventSerializer(User, data=request.headers)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response({'alert': 'registration successful'})
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

as in the method i used print method to find out the headers(for debugging i removed the permission class). CORS setting is not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the options/config as 3rd argument to [axios.put](https://github.com/axios/axios#browser). The 2nd argument is data/payload

**Like this**

```js
axios.put('http://localhost:8000/user-registration/', {}, config).then(
         res => {
            console.log(res.status)
         } 
      )
```